# selenium webdriver label automation in sequence verify

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

in image the numbering is not in sequence order, I need to verify if no are in sequence 1, 2, 3 , 4 then test case pass else fail.

Social Networking URL #1:
 text box

Social Networking URL #2:
text box
Social Networking URL #1:
textbox
Social Networking URL #1:
text box

To verify Numbering should go 1,2,3,4

please help, they are not allowing me to attach image for more clearance

Answer (score -1):

You can get the all elements by `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(css_selector)` with the given `css_selector` then you can get it text by `.text` finally check if the number is increasing sequencially:

Python:

```
def check_if_sequencial(css_selector):
    result = True
    elms = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(css_selector)

    for i in xrange(len(elms) - 1):
        text1 = elms[i].text
        text2 = elms[i+1].text

        # slicing after dash to end of string, convert to int
        number1 = int(text1[text1.index("#")+1 : len(text1)])
        number2 = int(text1[text2.index("#")+1 : len(text2)])

        if number2 != number1 + 1:
            print "number1: %d and number2: %d are not sequencial" %(number1, number2)
            result = False
            break

    return result
```

Java:

```
public boolean check_if_sequencial(String css_selector){
    boolean result = true;
    List elms = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(css_selector));

    for (int i = 0; i < elms.length - 1; i++) {
        String text1 = elms[i].text;
        String text2 = elms[i+1].text;

        # spliting by dash take the second, convert to int
        String[] parts1 = text1.split("#"); 
        int number1 = Integer.parseInt(parts1[1]);

        String[] parts2 = text2.split("#"); 
        int number2 = Integer.parseInt(parts2[1]);

        if (number2 != number1 + 1){
            System.out.println("number1: " + number1 + " and number2: " + number2 + " are not sequencial");

            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Social Networking URL #1: text box

Social Networking URL #2: text box
 Social Networking URL #1: textbox
 Social Networking URL #1: text box

Comment: boolean result = true;
      List <WebElement> elms = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='ucTeamInfo_updPnlTeamInfo']"));
      
    
         String[] linkTexts = new String[elms.size()];
         int i = 0;
  
         //extract the link texts of each link element
         for (WebElement e : elms) {
             linkTexts[i] = e.getText();
             i++;
         }

Comment: I am using above code which display all the feild details in the page

Comment: @abhiman I dont understand what is wrong with the code. is it worth for upvote? :)